# VerificationError: CompileError: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, couchbase, python-cffi

I am trying to install: [couchbase-python-cffi](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-python-cffi) as part of a PyPi package. But I keep on getting the following error when trying to install couchbase-python-cffi:

```
VerificationError: CompileError: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

This error only occurs on my Travis Build: https://travis-ci.org/ardydedase/pycouchbase/jobs/75819605#L541

Here's the content of my travis file:

```
# Config file for automatic testing at travis-ci.org

language: python

python:
  - "3.4"
  - "3.3"
  - "2.7"
  - "2.6"
  - "pypy"

before_install:
  - sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
  - wget -O- http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu/couchbase.key | sudo apt-key add -
  - echo deb http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu precise precise/main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchbase.list
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-cache search libcouchbase
  - sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev libffi6 libffi-dev
  - sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev

install:
  - sudo apt-get -y install libcouchbase-dev libcouchbase2-core libcouchbase2-libevent libevent-dev
  - pip -q install gevent || echo "Couldn't find gevent"
  - pip -q install twisted
  - pip -q install testresources
  - pip install -r requirements.txt

# command to run tests, e.g. python setup.py test
script: 
  - cd couchbase-python-cffi
  - python setup.py install
  - cd ..
  - python runtests.py
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated as this has been bothering me for quite a while.

Comment: The first error on the Travis log is ``error: ‘lcb_SYNCTOKEN’ undeclared``.  It looks like a missing ``#include`` in the cffi source code of couchbase_ffi.  I don't know why only on Travis...

Comment: Looking at further errors, maybe the problem is the version of ``libcouchbase-dev``.

Comment: @ArminRigo: Thanks for taking a look! Turns out I missed a cached header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *couchbase_cffi* module contains a "cached" header of the library (in `couchbase_ffi/_lcb.h`). That was generated against an older version of the library. Remove that file to force couchbase_cffi to regenerate that file again.

Comment: Thanks! After this one is solved, I encountered another issue that you might be able to help me with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056557/importerror-no-module-named-couchbase-libcouchbase