# Python Couchbase CFFI - `AssertionError: backend.__version__ == __version__[:3])`

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, couchbase, python-cffi

Full error text:

```
No module named couchbase._libcouchbase
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app_main.py", line 75, in run_toplevel
  File "runtests.py", line 12, in <module>
    mod = __import__(t, globals(), locals(), ['suite'])
  File "/home/travis/build/ardydedase/pycouchbase/tests/test_pycouchbase.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pycouchbase.utils import *
  File "/home/travis/build/ardydedase/pycouchbase/pycouchbase/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    import couchbase_ffi as couchase
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/pypy-2.5.0/site-packages/couchbase_ffi-0.2.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/couchbase_ffi/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    import couchbase_ffi._libcouchbase as _libcouchbase
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/pypy-2.5.0/site-packages/couchbase_ffi-0.2.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/couchbase_ffi/_libcouchbase.py", line 3, in <module>
    from couchbase_ffi._cinit import get_handle
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/pypy-2.5.0/site-packages/couchbase_ffi-0.2.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/couchbase_ffi/_cinit.py", line 13, in <module>
    ffi = FFI()
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/pypy-2.5.0/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 59, in __init__
    backend.__version__ == __version__[:3])
AssertionError
```

This only happens when I try to `import couchbase_ffi` in the PyPy build on Travis: https://travis-ci.org/ardydedase/pycouchbase/jobs/76043402#L1663

Details:

I have this in my `requirements.txt` for `couchbase-python-cffi`:

```
cffi==0.8.0
couchbase==2.0
```

Looks like an incompatibility issue with the packages. But not sure where it's coming from.

Comment: As this is alpha quality code, I am sure the developers would appreciate raising this as an issue at [the github repository](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-python-cffi).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: thanks for the suggestion. Raised a github issue: https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-python-cffi/issues/3

Comment: You have a broken installation of pypy - it should import it's own cffi and not pip installed one. You can't pip install a newer cffi on top of your PyPy, just get a new PyPy